# Mat-Table Selection only on current PageSize?

Tags: angular, typescript, datatable, angular-material

I'm building a table with pagination that handles some actions based on an array of selected checkboxes; I've the [docs](https://material.angular.io/components/table/overview#selection) and as far a just selecting ALL rows of just a few individually everything's good;

The scenario I'm trying to get to to work is the following: If my `PageSize` on my `paginator` is "10", and I click the `masterToggle` to select "all" rows, I want that to select all the rows on the current page, nothing more, so that would be the 10 rows that are being displayed with the current `PageSize`, however, this selects the whole `dataSource` of the table which is around 300 records.

Is there a way to make the `masterToggle` select only the rows that are displayed based on the PageSize? Then If I change the `PageSize` to 20 only the first 10 would stay selected.

This is my code.

```
/** Whether the number of selected elements matches the total number of rows. */
  isAllSelected() {
    const numSelected = this.selection.selected.length;
    const numRows = this.dataSource.data.length;
    return numSelected === numRows;
  }

  /** Selects all rows if they are not all selected; otherwise clear selection. */
  masterToggle() {
    this.isAllSelected() ?
        this.selection.clear() :
        this.dataSource.data.forEach(row => this.selection.select(row));
  }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Was able to get it to work by removin the last line on the `masterToggle()` method, and replacing that with a custom function that loops through the PageSize of the paginator and calls the `select` method of the `SelectionModel` for each alert it finds; I also changed the `isAllSelected` method to compare the `PageSize` and the selected `lenght` instead of the whole `dataSource`.

```
/** Whether the number of selected elements matches the total number of rows. */
  isAllSelected() {
    const numSelected = this.selection.selected.length;
    const page = this.dataSource.paginator.pageSize;
    return numSelected === page;
  }

  /** Selects all rows if they are not all selected; otherwise clear selection. */
  masterToggle() {
    this.isAllSelected() ? 
    this.selection.clear() : this.selectRows();
  }

  selectRows() {
    for (let index = 0; index < this.dataSource.paginator.pageSize; index++) {
      this.selection.select(this.dataSource.data[index]);
      this.selectionAmount = this.selection.selected.length;
    }
  }
```

Comment: Is there any way we can get this working while sorting is applied to datatable ? When sorting is applied , then above solution works but it selects records not on sorted data but which are loaded in its internal DATA attrbute . As a result , it selects random checkboxes

Comment: So far I haven't tried that, I do know that currenctly my selection will select by index, thus when sorting the indexes change and for example `index 0` can be like the 10th row on the table, leaving the other 9 before unchecked, it's something that surely can be made, I'll see if I try testing that later

Comment: What if you change the page? Your logic doesn't work.

Comment: @SrichandradeepC if you mean changing from page 1 to page 2, yes, the selection would no longer be there, if you mean increasing the page size, the selection remains there

Comment: Yes, the former. I just wanted to inform users who look for a different generic solution.

Answer (score 13):

If you're using sorting, paginating, and filtering:

HTML column:

```
<mat-checkbox (change)="$event ? masterToggle($event) : null"
    [checked]="selection.hasValue() && isEntirePageSelected()"
    [indeterminate]="selection.hasValue() && !isEntirePageSelected()"
    [aria-label]="checkboxLabel()"></mat-checkbox>
```

Component:

```
  getPageData() {
    return this.dataSource._pageData(this.dataSource._orderData(this.dataSource.filteredData));
  }

  isEntirePageSelected() {
    return this.getPageData().every((row) => this.selection.isSelected(row));
  }

  masterToggle(checkboxChange: MatCheckboxChange) {
    this.isEntirePageSelected() ?
      this.selection.deselect(...this.getPageData()) :
      this.selection.select(...this.getPageData());
  }

  checkboxLabel(row): string {
    if (!row) {
      return `${this.isEntirePageSelected() ? 'select' : 'deselect'} all`;
    }
    return `${this.selection.isSelected(row) ? 'deselect' : 'select'} row ${row.id + 1}`;
  }
```

Comment: The line `this.dataSource._pageData(this.dataSource._orderData(this.dataSource.filteredData))` is really helpful! It tells you exactly what items the table is currently showing (visible to the user) taking into account filtering, sorting, and the current pagination page index/page size.

Answer (score 2):

My solution is based on currently displayed rows so it works regarding the pagination.
There is a lot to improve about it so please feel free to make it better.

```
  isAllSelected() {

    const numSelected = this.selection.selected.length;
    const displayedRows = this.filteredEvents.connect().value.length;
    let isAllSelected = (numSelected === displayedRows);

    if (isAllSelected) {
      isAllSelected = this.isAllDisplayedSelected();
    }

    return isAllSelected;
  }

  isAllDisplayedSelected() {
    let isAllDisplayedSelected = true;

    if (this.selection.selected.length === 0) {
      return this.isAllSelected();
    }

    this.filteredEvents.connect().value.some(element => {
      if (!this.selection.isSelected(element)) {
        isAllDisplayedSelected = false;
        return isAllDisplayedSelected;
      }
    });
    return isAllDisplayedSelected;
  }

  masterToggle() {
    this.isViewableSelected() ?
      this.deselectRows() :
      this.selectRows();
  }

  isViewableSelected() {
    return (this.isAllSelected() || this.isAllDisplayedSelected());
  }

  deselectRows() {
    const itemsToBeUnselected = this.filteredEvents.connect().value;
    itemsToBeUnselected.forEach(element => {
      this.selection.deselect(element);
    });
  }

  selectRows() {
    const currentlyDisplayedRows = this.filteredEvents.connect().value;

    for (let index = 0; index < currentlyDisplayedRows.length; index++) {
      this.selection.select(currentlyDisplayedRows[index]);
      this.selectionAmount = this.selection.selected.length;
    }
  }
```

The HTML:

```
<ng-container matColumnDef="select">
  <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>
    <mat-checkbox (change)="$event ? masterToggle() : null" [checked]="selection.hasValue() && isViewableSelected()"
      [indeterminate]="selection.hasValue() && !isViewableSelected()">
    </mat-checkbox>
  </th>
  <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row">
    <mat-checkbox (click)="$event.stopPropagation()" (change)="$event ? selection.toggle(row) : null"
      [checked]="selection.isSelected(row)">
    </mat-checkbox>
  </td>
</ng-container>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is my solution.
https://angular-vkz1dp.stackblitz.io
I build in an extra if switch page it will uncheck.

HTML column:

```
<mat-checkbox #ref
       (click)="$event.stopPropagation()"
       (change)="$event ? masterToggle(ref) : null"></mat-checkbox>
```

HTML cell:

```
<mat-checkbox (click)="$event.stopPropagation()"
                    [checked]="selection.isSelected(element)"></mat-checkbox>
```

HTML paginator:

```
<mat-paginator fixed [pageSizeOptions]="[20, 50, 100]" [pageSize]="20" (page)="pageChange()" showFirstLastButtons></mat-paginator>
```

Component:

```
  @ViewChild('ref') ref: any;

  masterToggle(_ref: any) {
    if(_ref.checked){
        this.checkPageOnly();
    }
    else {
        this.selection.clear();
    }
  }

  checkPageOnly() {
      let i = this.dataSource.paginator.pageIndex * this.dataSource.paginator.pageSize;
      let end = (this.dataSource.paginator.pageIndex + 1) * this.dataSource.paginator.pageSize;
      for(i; i < end; i++) {
        this.selection.select(this.dataSource.data[i]);
      }
  }

    pageChange() {
        this.ref.checked = false;
        this.masterToggle(this.ref);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I found an easier way to do this (Angular):
Instead of `this.dataSource.data.length` change it to `this.dataSource.connect().value.forEach(row => this.selection.select(row));`
Something like:

```
  masterToggle() {
    this.isAllSelected() ?
    this.selection.clear() :
    this.dataSource.connect().value.forEach(row => this.selection.select(row));
  }
```

But the only problem here is, that it won't clear all the selected fields; so to achieve this, change your isAllSelected() method :

```
  isAllSelected() {
    const numSelected = this.selection.selected.length;
    const numRows = this.dataSource.paginator != undefined ? this.dataSource.paginator.pageSize : 5;
    return numSelected === numRows;
 }
```

Here "5" is your original page size, defined until your dataSource doesn't gets initialized.

Comment: It works well! I just added two other events to clean the selection when the paginator changes or some columns are ordered, because in both cases the deselection fails.  **onPageChange(event: PageEvent){
    this.selection.clear();
  }**
**onSortChange(event: Sort) {
    this.selection.clear(); 
  }**


HTML:
**<table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" (matSortChange)="onSortChange($event)">**
...
**<mat-paginator [pageSizeOptions]="[10,20, 100, 200]" showFirstLastButtons (page)="onPageChange($event)"> **

Answer (score 0):

```
          isAllSelected() {
              // const numSelected = this.selection.selected.length;
              // const numRows = this.dataSource.data.length;
              // return numSelected === numRows;
              // const page = this.dataSource.paginator.pageSize;
              // return numSelected === page;
              return this.selection.selected.length > 0;
            }

            /** Selects all rows if they are not all selected; otherwise clear selection. */
            masterToggle() {
              this.isAllSelected() ?
                this.selection.clear() :
                // this.dataSource.data.forEach(row => this.selection.select(row));
                this.selectRows();
            }
            pageChanged(event) {
              this.selection.clear();
            }
            selectRows() {

              const intIndex = this.dataSource.paginator.pageIndex === 0 ? 0 : (this.dataSource.paginator.pageSize * this.dataSource.paginator.pageIndex);
              let intPageSize = intIndex + this.dataSource.paginator.pageSize;
              if (intPageSize > this.dataSource.filteredData.length) {
                intPageSize = this.dataSource.filteredData.length;
              }
              for (let index = intIndex; index < intPageSize; index++) {
                this.selection.select(this.dataSource.filteredData[index]);
                // this.selectionAmount = this.selection.selected.length;
              }
            }


            /** The label for the checkbox on the passed row */
            checkboxLabel(row?: TicketMatchingElement): string {
              if (!row) {
                return `${this.isAllSelected() ? 'select' : 'deselect'} all`;
              }
              return `${this.selection.isSelected(row) ? 'deselect' : 'select'} row ${row.bookingId + 1}`;
            }
            formatDateValue(dateValue: Date) {
              return formatDate(dateValue);
            }
          }
```

HTML just change in the paginatory

```
<mat-paginator [pageSizeOptions]="[5, 10, 20,25]"
        showFirstLastButtons (page)="pageChanged($event)"
      ></mat-paginator>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just found [this answer](https://github.com/angular/components/issues/9419#issuecomment-363352337)

You can use `datasource.connect().value` to get all items that are currently rendered in your table.

So from your code you could do:

```
masterToggle() {
    this.isAllSelected() ?
        this.selection.clear() :
        this.dataSource.connect().value.forEach(row => this.selection.select(row));
  }
```